# System.currentTimeMillis() giving wrong time in hours

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my app to display a time, and for that I need to get the android's minutes and hours. I'm trying to use `currentTimeMillis()`, but I'm getting the wrong number for the hours. Here's my code for the hours and minutes using the systems clock.

```
    int defday = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    int defhour = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - (defday * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
            / (1000 * 60 * 60);
    int defmin = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()
            - (defhour * 1000 * 60 * 60) - (defday * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
            / (1000 * 60);
```

After I run the app, the time shows the time as `5:36` even though the current time is `1:36`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Timezone? currentTimeMillis is in UTC time

Comment: +1, it doesn't look like you're doing anything to handle which timezone you're in. If only the hours are off, this seems to be the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Calendar object:

```
long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(millis);
```

After this you can get the fields from the Calendar object:

```
int hours=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minutes=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Then:

int MinutesHours=(hours*60)+minutes;
To go back, you can use the set method in Calendar:

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);
long millis=c.getTimeInMillis();
```

**References**

[How to measure the a time-span in seconds using System.currentTimeMillis()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317750/how-to-convert-system-currenttimemillis-to-seconds)

[currentTimeMillis() to Years, days, and minutes, and backwords. (hard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014325/currenttimemillis-to-years-days-and-minutes-and-backwords-hard)

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly with what I'm trying to do